# Regex date formatting for templates not working

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace variables like {{{month}}} in a template to the current month and {{{month+1}}} to current month + 1.
That's not the hardest part of my code, except that the regex I wrote doesn't yield expected results.

```
$string = '{{{year}}}{{{month+1}}}';
preg_match_all('/{{{(?:([yY])ear|([mM])onth|([dD])ay)(?:(?<operation>[-|+])(?<amount>[1-9]+))?}}}/m', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Why do I have so much empty array entries?
I was expecting

```
[0] => array('{{{year}}}', '{{{month+1}}}')
[1] => array('y', 'm')
[2] => array('', '+')
[3] => array('', '1')
```

What am I doing wrong?

The respond of the above code is:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "{{{year}}}"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "{{{month+1}}}"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "y"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(1) "m"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["operation"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(1) "+"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(1) "+"
  }
  ["amount"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the capturing groups where not necessary, or turn them into non-capturing groups. E.g. `preg_match_all('/{{{(?:[yY]ear|[mM]onth|[dD]ay)(?:(?<operation>[-|+])(?<amount>[1-9]+))?}}}/m', $string, $matches);`

Comment: If remove the grouping, I will can't catch the yYmMdD anymore
And, the output is still not I'm expecting it

Comment: You can still revert named capturing groups to numbered ones. That will clear it  a bit. Note that it is not possible to get rid of empty captures if you have set a capturing group.

Comment: I changed it to: `preg_match_all('/{{{([yY]ear|[mM]onth|[dD]ay)(?:([-|+])([1-9]+))?}}}/m', $string, $matches);`

Now it works almost as I want it, but what's the best way to catch the yYmMdD in this case, without causing empty captures?

Comment: Maybe [`preg_match_all('/{{{([yYmMdD])(?:(?<=[Yy])ear|(?<=[Mm])onth|(?<=[Dd])ay)(?:([-+])([1-9]+))?}}}/m', $string, $matches);`](http://ideone.com/UeItQ9)?

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev! After asking my question about the catching the "alias" I started to think about negative lookbehind.

Your solution works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a "generic" character class to match the first letters of `month`, `year` and `day`, and then use an alternation with positive look-behinds to make sure we match what we need.

```
preg_match_all('/{{{([yYmMdD])(?:(?<=[Yy])ear|(?<=[Mm])onth|(?<=[Dd])ay)(?:([-‌​+])([1-9]+))?}}}/m', $string, $matches);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/UeItQ9)

And this is the `print_r` view:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{{year}}}
            [1] => {{{month+1}}}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => y
            [1] => m
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => +
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking to use negative lookbehind, but wasn't done making it workable.
Now I can use the group-naming even better :)
`{{{(?<format>[yYmMdD])(?:(?<=[Yy])ear|(?<=[Mm])onth|(?<=[Dd])ay)(?:(?<operation>[-+])(?<amount>[1-9]+))?}}}`